# UICollectionview is empty

Tags: ios, storyboard, nsarray, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi  i have created one `UIViewController` in that i added one `UICollectionView` with CustomCell. Then, i created a `uicollectionviewcell` class for cell. Finally set the delegate and datasource in storybord itself. But it showing empty page. like in below image

[image]

CODE:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.collectionview = _collectionview;
    self.collectionview.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionview.delegate = self;

    speakersImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imageLabels=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"RB Forum 2013",@"Agenda",@"Speakers",@"Contact",@"Map",@"Websites",@"@Responsible Biz",@"Partners",@"Sustainability",nil];


    imagePaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RBform.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"agenda.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"speakers.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"website.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"partners.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"sustainability.png"], nil];
    [self.collectionview registerClass:[NewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];



}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imageLabels count];
}

//THE BELOW DELEGATE METHOD DOES NOT GET CALLED!


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold an image and its label
    //
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value

    cell.labels.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    // load the image for this cell
    NSLog(@"%@",imageLabels);
    //NSString *imageToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.JPG", indexPath.row];
    //    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad];
    cell.images.image = [imagePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your NewCell is custom class?

Comment: YES Deepak its my custome class

Comment: Are any of the datasource methods being called?

Comment: means? i didnt get you?

Answer (score 22):

Solution  is remove 
[self.collectionview registerClass:[NewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

in storybord we dont need this

Comment: Are you sure?  In cases where I was using custom collectionview cells (Class + XIB) I found I had to register both the Class and the Nib.  Registering the NIB allowed the view to show, but registering the Class forced [dequeue] to return a custom cell.  Perhaps it's because my custom class doesn't load the NIB but the XIB sets the class of the collection view cell to my custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Code is ok but order is different.Assigning datasource and delegates before array is populated makes the number of cell returned to 0 ,since array is not yet  populated

Try like this

```
    speakersImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imageLabels=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"RB Forum 2013",@"Agenda",@"Speakers",@"Contact",@"Map",@"Websites",@"@Responsible Biz",@"Partners",@"Sustainability",nil];


    imagePaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RBform.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"agenda.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"speakers.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"website.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"partners.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"sustainability.png"], nil];
    [self.collectionview registerClass:[NewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
   [self.collectionview reloadData];
```

this line is not needed

```
self.collectionview = _collectionview;
self.collectionview.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionview.delegate = self;
```

also make sure your collection view is connected via outlet

**make sure the `<UICollectioniewDatasource,UICollectionviewDelegate>` is there in the class header**

Comment: is the outlet proper and datasource and delegate connected via ib?

Comment: Remove the custom class name and make it uicollectionviewcell

Comment: App crashed  with following message [UICollectionViewCell labels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d5ba50
2013-11-07 12:51:15.528 RBForm[4590:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell labels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d5ba50'

Answer (score 0):

1. In Your storyboard give your `imageview` a `tag` e.g. 1, and your `label` another `tag` e.g. 2
2. Give your `cell` reuse identifier that you have already gave eg. "`Cell`"
3. Now in your storyboard right click on `collection view` and create `datasource` and `delegate` to your viewController or file owner. alternatively you can use `<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>` in your viewController and set the delegate and datasource to self.
4. Now in your viewDidLoad

-`(void)` `viewDidLoad` {

```
            self.collectionview.dataSource = self;
            self.collectionview.delegate = self;
        
            speakersImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            imageLabels=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"RB Forum   2013",@"Agenda",@"Speakers",@"Contact",@"Map",@"Websites",@"@Responsible     Biz",@"Partners",@"Sustainability",nil];
        
        
            imagePaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RBform.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"agenda.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"speakers.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"website.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"partners.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"sustainability.png"], nil];
        
        }
```

6. number of items in collection view

   - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {

     ```
           return [imageLabels count];
       }
     ```
7. create cell and reuse

   - `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
     {

     ```
                   UICollectionView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

                   // make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value

                   UIlabel *label = (UIlabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2]
                   label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageLabels   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

                   // load the image for this cell
                   UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1]
                   imageView.image = [imagePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                   return cell;

               }
     ```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];

    self.collectionview.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionview.delegate = self;


self.imageLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"RB Forum 2013",@"Agenda",@"Speakers",@"Contact",@"Map",@"Websites",@"@Responsible Biz",@"Partners",@"Sustainability",nil];

self.imagePaths=[NSArray arrayWithObjects::@"RBform.png",@"agenda.png",@"speakers.png",@"contact.png",@"map.png",@"website.png",@"twitter.png",@"partners.png",@"sustainability.png", nil];



}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.imageLabels count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.labels.text = [self.imageLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagePaths objectAtIndex:index path.row]];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: It crashed with  following messsage due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/NAVEEN/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/E1951DA5-05BA-4D6C-B560-F160BC373249/RBForm.app> (loaded)' with name 'NewCell''

Comment: Give your UICollectionViewCell name

Comment: are you created xib for NewCell?

Comment: No am using Storybord...Can u give ur mail id then i can send this file to you